# How to reference a single column in a def function

Tags: python, pandas

First off I know using regular expression is not the best email validation but this is a preliminary step, a better validation comes later.

I want to create a function that validates whether or not an email address is valid but i am not sure how to reference only one column in a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

d=[['Automotive','testgmail.com','bob','smith']]
df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['industry','email','first',last])

filename='temp'
```

**I want to keep the code in a def function like the one below**

```
def Prospect(colname,errors):
   wrong=[]
   if #reference to column.str.match(r"^.+@.+\..{2,}$"):
       return
    else:
    error='this is an invalid email'
    wrong.append(error)
       return wrong
    
               
print(Prospect(errors,colname))
```

How do I create a function to only reference a specific column in a data frame and only run that column name through the function and create a print statement saying that the email is invalid?

P.S: speed of the operation is not a huge concern since the datasets are not massive.

desired output:

```
This is an invalid email
```

Comment: use `validate_email` package instead. then you just have to do `df['email'].apply(lambda x: validate_email(x))` -> returns a bool

Comment: I understand that it can be done this way but i need it to go to a function since reference the function later on for other things. How do i reference just the email column in a def function?

Comment: df["email"] ...

Comment: i would like to stick with the example of the code i was looking for in my question `def Prospect`

Comment: In your function, I imagine the colname argument would be 'email', but what does the argument errors stand for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might want:

```
def Prospect(colname, errors, df=df):
    
    m = df[colname].str.match(r"^.+@.+\..{2,}$")
    
    if m.all():
        pass
    else:
        error='this is an invalid email'
        errors.append(error)
    
errors = []
Prospect('email', errors, df=df)

print(errors)
```

output: `['this is an invalid email']`

Comment: df['email'] -> df[colname] otherwise no need for colname arg

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

d=[['Automotive','testgmail.com','bob','smith'],
   ['Automotive','test@gmail.com','bob','smith']]
df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['industry','email','first','last'])

email_regex = regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$'

df["email"].apply(lambda email: print("This is a valid email: " + email if re.search(email_regex,email) else "This is an invalid email: " + email))
```

Results in:

```
This is an invalid email: testgmail.com
This is a valid email: test@gmail.com

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Is this possible to put into a def function as i need to reference this function later on. it makes things for the validation more complex but it makes the overall code simpler. @noah

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's my take on your question (I've removed the "errors" argument until I understand what it's supposed to be/do):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

d=[['Automotive','testgmail.com','bob','smith'],
   ['Automotive','test@gmail.com','bob','smith']]
df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['industry','email','first','last'])

def Prospect(colname):
    email_regex = r"^.+@.+\..{2,}$"
    wrong=[]
    for i in range(len(df)):
        this_email = df[colname][i]
        if re.search(email_regex,this_email):
            continue
        else:
            error=f'{this_email} is an invalid email'
            wrong.append(error)
    return wrong

print(Prospect('email'))
# ['testgmail.com is an invalid email']
```